# Synchronizing two Databases

Tags: .net, database

The Requierement is like this,

I am a dotnet Develooper.I have one dotnet web application and we need to maintain two servers A and B.what ever the data entered into the "A" db ,will also need to inserted into "B" db.If any slow or shutdown happend to db 'A" then immideatly connect to db "B" and again if "A" db is free then switch back to "A" db.

Q) how to do this or how to achieve this ?
Q) As a developer how much i can achieve In this? 
Q) who will do this work(mean dotnet developer or DBA person or networking team.etc)?

Please help me .....thanks in advance.

Comment: First thought: set up a database replication strategy on the DBMS

Comment: *how to do this or how to achieve this* - **By Researching, Trying** | *As a developer how much i can achieve In this* - **Researching Again ([Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=synchronize+two+databases+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=6npeUrfhO82trAex4YCABw))** *who will do this work* - **Really bad question**

Comment: thanks for replies , i unable to getting this can you please explain with one sample. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We use the `Microsoft Sync Framework` for this task. It allows to sync Files and Databases in both directions. We are using it to sync two sql servers and it works like a charm.

You just need to provisionate the tables because it creates some metadata. But you can find a lot of examples on msdn.

more info here:

[Introduction to Sync Framework Database Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/sync/bb887608)

And some code here:

[How to: Execute Database Synchronization (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd918848.aspx)

You could also use `Transactional replication`. It allows data to be updated at both databases:

[How Transactional Replication Works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151706.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use database mirroring.
Mirroring makes two databases synchronized and if you use it on high safety mode with witness when failure accures automaticaly switches the database to another one.
 DBA implement mirroring. But aslo developers in their code and connections should mention failover server.So the web server automaticaly connects other database on failure.